# Bash scripting: Diference between "$(command)" and `command`

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, sh

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Command substitution: backticks or dollar sign / paren enclosed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9405478/command-substitution-backticks-or-dollar-sign-paren-enclosed)

I want know the difference between use

```
var="$(command)"
```

and

```
var=`command`
```

in bash scripting, aparently are two ways to get the same result, but is possible that exist some diferences.

Comment: Flagged as a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9405478/command-substitution-backticks-or-dollar-sign-paren-enclosed

Comment: Thanks you and sorry for duplicate, I dont know that it is too called "substitution" and forget look with something words similar to that. Thanks you again...

Comment: No problem.  It's a pain to find by searching if you haven't seen it before.

Answer (score 1):

The first is better, as you can nest the command substitutions and it doesn't become awkward.

[Further Reading](http://www.c3.hu/docs/oreilly/unix/upt/ch45_31.htm).

Answer (score 1):

From [bash man page](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution):

> When the old-style backquote form of substitution is used, backslash retains its literal meaning except when followed by ‘$’, ‘`’, or ‘\’. The first backquote not preceded by a backslash terminates the command substitution. When using the $(command) form, all characters between the parentheses make up the command; none are treated specially.

(more interesting things there; do read the whole thing :) )