# Using variable with cp in bash

Tags: linux, bash, variables, cp

The file returned will have spaces in the file name so I run the file name through sed to append quotes at the beginning and end. However, when I use $CF with cp it fails. If I manually echo $CF and use the resulting file in place of $CF it works just fine. What's the problem?

```
CF=`ls -tr /mypath/CHS1*.xlsx | tail -1 | sed -e 's/^/"/g' -e 's/$/"/g'`
cp $CF "/mydest/myfile.xlsx"
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You don't need to add the quotes like that (in fact, it probably won't work).  Instead, just use them in the `cp` line:

```
CF=$(ls -tr /mypath/CHS1*.xlsx | tail -1)
cp "$CF" "/mydest/myfile.xlsx"
```

I changed it from using backticks to the newer ([and preferred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9405478/command-substitution-backticks-or-dollar-sign-paren-enclosed)) `$()` syntax.