# Restructure makefile to avoid redundant implementation

Tags: bash, shell, makefile

A part of my `makefile` is as follow:

```
list1:          all
                for f in \
                `less fetch/list1.txt`; \
                do \
                    ...
                    ./$(BIN) $$f & \
                    ...
                done

list2:          all
                for f in \
                `less fetch/list2.txt`; \
                do \
                    ...
                    ./$(BIN) $$f & \
                    ...
                done
```

`fetch/list1.txt` and `fetch/list2.txt` contains two lists of files (path+filename), and `make list1` and `make list2` will respectively go through the 2 lists and run `$(BIN)` again the files. This works fine.

The problem is that, I have a couple of file lists as `list1` and `list2`, and the process of the make is always the same. Does anyone know how to simplify `makefile` such that `make listA`, `make list4`, etc. does what they are supposed to do?

Comment: `for f in `less fetch/list2.txt``???? are you feeling alright?

Comment: I don't see where is the problem... That does work...

Comment: Definitely an unorthodox use of `less` which is intended to display a file to your terminal page by page.  But it works because the command in the command substitution backticks does not have a terminal, and thus less degenerates to displaying the file in one go, which I think is what you want.  More regular usage would be something like `$(cat fetch/list1.txt)`.  Also note `$()` generally preferred over backticks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9405478/command-substitution-backticks-or-dollar-sign-paren-enclosed

Comment: I tried `for f in $(cat fetch/$@.txt)`, that returns nothing...

Comment: You need to escape the `$` in the make body so the shell gets it. That is you need `$$(cat ...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [Pattern Rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules):

```
all:
    @echo "The all recipe"

list%: all
    @echo "This recipe does something with $@.txt"
```

Output is:

```
$ make list1
The all recipe
This recipe does something with list1.txt
$ make list256
The all recipe
This recipe does something with list256.txt
$
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend performing scripting within makefiles.  It will very often lead to arbitrary, inconsistent bugs, and other forms of frustration.

Use Make for execution control with dependencies, (as in, determining what gets executed when) but write your actual primitives (scripts or other programs) seperately, and call them from within Make.

```
bar:    foo1 foo2 foo3

# bar is the make target.  Foo1, 2, and 3 are sub-targets needed to make bar.

foo1:
    fooscript1    # Written as an individual script, outside Make.
    fooscript2
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
all:
        @echo "All"

action_%:
    @./$(BIN) $*

ACTION=$(patsubst %,action_%,$(shell cat $(ACT_FILE)))

actionList:
    @make $(ACTION)

list%:  all
    @make ACT_FILE=fetch/list$*.txt actionList
```

Supports all list :-)

Rather than allow infinite parallelism (you were using `./$(BIN) fileName &`). You can control actual parallelism using Make's built in features.

```
 make -j8 list1
 #      ^  Parallelism set to 8
```