# Unix `cp` command with $ sign

Tags: unix, cp, dollar-sign

This question is regarding the Unix `cp` command.

What is the `$(...)` operator doing below?

`cp $(bundle show bootstrap-sass)/vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap.scss \
 app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap-custom.scss`

I came across this notation from the page: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass#usage

I checked the man page for cp and did not see any references to this operation. I'm new to *nix. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In shell scripting, the `$(...)` executes the commands in the parenthesis and returns the text printed to STDOUT by that command.  This also applies to the backtick notation as well.

For example: `echo $(date) - This is a dated line` will print something like `Thu Jun 26 10:08:20 CDT 2014 - This is a dated line`

Here's another [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9405478/command-substitution-backticks-or-dollar-sign-paren-enclosed) on the topic.

Comment: Very clear. Thanks for the example. I'll accept your answer as soon as SO allows me to.

Comment: 1 other point (of trivia ;-) ). This is known as `command-substitution`.  You will often see another form of command-substitution that uses single back-tick characters (on each end) surround the cmd whose output is to be used. (Hard to illustrate in an S.O. comment). However, `$(...)` is the definitely preferred form, as back-ticks have been marked as deprecated in Kornshell since at least 1995.

Comment: @shellter - Absolutely! Unless you can't avoid it, the backtick version should be avoided.  It's harder to read and much harder to nest.  I think the question linked in the answer touches on this a bit.

Comment: @Mr.Llama: Yep!  And Hey, I said hard to illustrate in S.O. comment, but just notice that O.P. has back-tics surrounding the `cp` cmd in the title! :-) . Unfortunately, `cp` doesn't return output to stdout, so not a good example of cmd-sub. ;-/ Good luck to all!

Answer (score 1):

`$()` evaluate contents of brackets before the main command.