# Kill process by pid file

Tags: linux

I try to kill a process by pid file:

```
kill -9 $(cat /var/run/myProcess.pid)
```

The pid file contains the process number. However executing the kill gives me no stdout and the processes is still alive. But this works:

```
kill -9 PID
```

What is wrong with the first kill command? Does it fail to extract the PID from the file?

Example content of pid file:

```
5424
```

and

```
kill -9 5424
```

works.

Comment: I'm guessing, but try `cat /var/run/myProcess.pid | xargs kill -9`; my assumption is that you have trailing white-space in the pid file.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch nope is not working

Comment: Post the contents of the pid file.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch just a number, see my updated question

Comment: @ElliottFrisch yes it prints 5424.

Comment: @artworkadシ Does ``kill -9 `cat /var/run/myProcess.pid` `` work? (had to figure out how to print backticks inside of backticks, heh)

Comment: Is this in a script, or at the command line? If it's a script what is your shebang line and are you on Ubuntu?

Comment: @admdrew this works, can you explain where the difference is?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I am on debian, and the command is called from a nodejs script. The problem was solved with kill -9 `cat /var/run/myProcess.pid`

Comment: @artworkadシ Is your `/bin/sh` bash, or is it dash?

Comment: @artworkadシ I actually didn't know; looks like they're equivalent, but `$()` is the newer [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_03) ([source1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9405478/command-substitution-backticks-or-dollar-sign-paren-enclosed), [source2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708549/shell-programming-whats-the-difference-between-command-and-command))

Comment: Be aware most of the times `-9` is not required and not recommended. Give process a chance to properly cleanup its resources.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

I believe you are experiencing this because your default shell is [dash](https://wiki.debian.org/DashAsBinSh) (the debian almquist shell), but you are using bash syntax. You can specify bash in the shebang line with something like,

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

Or, you could use the dash and bash compatible back-tick expression suggested by [admdrew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1454048/admdrew) in the comments

```
kill -9 `cat /var/run/myProcess.pid`
```

Regardless, you can't rely on `/bin/sh` to be bash.

Answer (score 88):

In some situations, the more compact:

```
pkill -F /var/run/myProcess.pid
```

is the way to go. I've had trouble with the varieties:

```
kill $(cat /var/run/myProcess.pid)
# Or
kill `cat /var/run/myProcess.pid`
```

when I had to put the command into something else which might parse it using different rules, like [Monit](https://mmonit.com/monit/) does for its start/stop commands.

Answer (score 4):

```
cat /var/run/myProcess.pid | sudo xargs kill -9
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

There is very simple method.

```
fuser -k /path/filename
```

example lets say you wanna kill apt lock file in linux.

```
sudo fuser -k /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

and it will kill the process that holds the file.