# Can't check checksum in bash --- apparently, wrong syntax?

Tags: bash

I have this bit of code, that is supposed to call `reload` if current file (`$1`) is changed:

```
thehash="`cksum $1`"

while true
do
    curhash="`cksum $1`"
    if "$curhash" -ne "$thehash"; then
        reload
    fi
    ...
done
```

tl;dr: it doesn't work.

Since I am not very experienced with bash, I can't figure out what did I do wrong. I get this error:

```
58003725 834183 main.pdf: command not found
```

Apparently, bash is trying to execute `curhash`? How do I fix this?

Comment: not sure what is wrong, but you can start by using this syntax `thehash=$(cksum "$1")` instead of ``thehash="`cksum $1`"`` ..

Comment: see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters/131767#131767 and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need brackets around your condition in `if` or to use the `test` command, so it should be

```
if [[ "$curhash" != "$thehash" ]]; then
```

and note that `-ne` is for integer comparison, `!=` is for string comparison

Without the `[[` or `test` the variable gets expanded and that becomes a command to run, which is why it was trying to execute the output of `cksum`: the content of `curhash` was being treated as a command.

Also, as @Sundeep mentioned the more often preferred way to get the output from the subshell is to use `$(...)` instead of the backticks.  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9406350/4687135) is a good answer talking about that

Comment: Oh! I've tried using brackets, but they didn't help; I did not pay attention and didn't notice that they are separated with spaces! Bash is complicated... Anyway, thank you so much!

Comment: @Akiiino http://www.shellcheck.net/ is very useful then and don't forget to quote your variables... ex: `"$1"`

Comment: @Akiiino white space is often important in bash, that's what it uses to tokenize (a.k.a., word splitting)

Comment: @Sundeep good point about quoting the variables. shellcheck.net is great and highlighted the backticks question, but it didn't catch this particular problem because the code was valid syntax, it just wasn't semantically correct