# Pass incremental value from empty hive table

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, sqoop

I have a hive table in hive that is empty. Now I want to do incremental imports for this table.

When I query the table

```
last_val = `hive -e "select max(id) from db.table"
```

I am getting a `NULL` value.

How can I pass this value to the sqoop incremental query.`Say If null then pass as Zero or something`

Comment: You don't need to maintain two accounts Interested_User and Active_User. One is sufficient.

Comment: @devツ No that is not my account I have checked the question of that user and got a doubt so posted a new question. As I have not enough reps to comment for that question

Comment: @Intrested_user I think 50reps should allow you to comment everywhere.

Comment: @Intrested_user  Your question is already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43103386/2700344

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below query to replace `NULL` with 0.

```
last_val = `hive -e "select NVL(max(id),0) from db.table"
```

Comment: @Intrested_user its available in Hive. Check : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-2288