# Why do people use grave accent instead of dollar and parentheses in g++?

Tags: bash, g++

As I compiling code with opencv, I found that people use pkg-config to get include and link information. For example,

```
g++ main.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
```

However, as this post: [Command substitution: backticks or dollar sign / paren enclosed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9405478/command-substitution-backticks-or-dollar-sign-paren-enclosed) says, using $() is preferred.

`g++ main.cpp $(pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv)`

It seems that grave accent is more frequently in this situation. Why?

Comment: Back-ticks (as they are usually called) are older and because of that more ingrained in peoples mind.

Comment: Also, this have *nothing* to do with GCC or the `g++` command.

Comment: And/or, people don't learn shell properly, they just copy/paste somebody's broken code.

Comment: To be fair, the thing that is broken here is `pkg-config` itself (by design), since it is assumed that the output can be used unquoted as arguments to `g++`.

Comment: A lot of folk grump about having to type a WHOLE EXTRA CHARACTER, but once they hit a situation where they need to embed one subcommand in another those self-matching parens start to look pretty good. :)