# Unable to print the public ip in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Hi I am trying to print the public ip of the machine in a file using shell script. I am using the command

```
ip=${curl ipinfo.io/ip}
```

in my script file and it gives an error saying bad substitution. whereas this command works when i run it in command line.
Is this the right way to get the ip through the script?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a variable to the output of a command in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4651437/608639), [What is the difference between $(command) and \`command\` in shell programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4708549/608639), [Command substitution: backticks or dollar sign / paren enclosed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9405478/608639), etc.

Answer (score 2):

You are capturing the result of program so you should use `$()`.  The following should work for you (with the `-s` parameter to `curl` stopping unnecessary output)

```
ip=$(curl -s ipinfo.io/ip)
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks for that!!!