# double quotation bash scripting linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I do not understand why the output is the username because in line 3 and 4 must print `/usr/bin/whoami`.
please explantation simple to me

```
#!/bin/bash

WHEREWHOAMI="`which whoami`"
ROOTORNOT="`$WHEREWHOAMI`"
echo "$ROOTORNOT"
```

Comment: Run the script with `set -x` to see what the commands expand to.

Comment: I often find [explainshell](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=WHEREWHOAMI%3D%22%60which+whoami%60%22+ROOTORNOT%3D%22%60%24WHEREWHOAMI%60%22+echo+%22%24ROOTORNOT%22) to be of use in these scenarios.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between $(command) and \`command\` in shell programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4708549/608639) and [Command substitution: backticks or dollar sign / paren enclosed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9405478/608639)

Comment: Related to using `which`, you usually want to use `command -v`. Also see [How to check if a program exists from a Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/592620/608639) and [How to check if command exists in a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7522712/608639)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `ROOTORNOT` is set to the output of the execution of `WHEREWHOAMI` which in turn is the output of the command `which whoami`.

```
WHEREWHOAMI=`which whoami`  # <- /usr/bin/whoami
ROOTWHOAMI="`$WHEREWHOAMI`" # <- `/usr/bin/whoami`  # <- username
```

You can easily figure out what is going on if you add the `set -x` flag to your script. Example:

```
$ set -x
$ WHEREWHOAMI="`which whoami`"
++ alias
++ declare -f
++ /usr/bin/which --tty-only --read-alias --read-functions --show-tilde --show-dot whoami
+ WHEREWHOAMI=/usr/bin/whoami
$ ROOTORNOT="`$WHEREWHOAMI`"
++ /usr/bin/whoami
+ ROOTORNOT=kvantour
$ echo "$ROOTORNOT"
+ echo kvantour
kvantour
$
```

Answer (score 1):

Backticks are evaluated even inside double quotes.
(Suggestion - don't use backticks. use `$()` instead.)

```
WHEREWHOAMI="`which whoami`"
```

This executes `which whoami` and assigns `/usr/bin/whoami` to `WHEREWHOAMI`.

```
ROOTORNOT="`$WHEREWHOAMI`"
```

This executes `/usr/bin/whoami` in backticks, and assigns the USERNAME result to `ROOTORNOT`.

It's doing exactly what it should.
Is that not what you indended?

Perhaps what you wanted was something like -

```
$: [[ $( $(which whoami) ) == root ]] && echo ROOT || echo not-root
not-root
```

Though I do suggest storing the value and comparing that.
Is there a reason you can't just use

```
if [[ root == "$LOGNAME" ]] 
then : ...
```

?

Comment: thanks and yes dear paul