# Running function with read command in bash

Tags: bash, function

I need small help with shell function.
I created small function with read command inside, I need to call this function and the return value to outside variable

```
Check()
{
echo "type something : "
read anyword
echo $anyword
}


out=`Check`
echo $out
```

the problem is that echo line is not presenting anything until i press enter.
I want that this function will act like python.

Thanks,

Comment: Please note that `$()` syntax has been preferred over backticks since....a really long time ago.  Probably circa 1992.  Backticks are bad for your health, bad for the planet, and may cause cancer.  Also, a kitten dies every time you use them.

Comment: To @WilliamPursell's point, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9405478/command-substitution-backticks-or-dollar-sign-paren-enclosed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the backticks. If you `CTRL+C` before the prompt ends, and try to echo `$out`, you notice that your prompt is saved into the `$out` variable. Move the prompt outside the function call. Maybe this will help:

```
Check()
{
    read anyword
    echo $anyword
}

echo "type something : "
out=`Check`
echo $out
```

If you're using bash specifically, consider `read -p` also.

Alternatively, if you want to keep the prompt inside the function:

```
Check()
{
    echo "Type something: " >&2
    read anyword
    echo $anyword
}
```

That way, it will write to stderr instead of stdout, so it won't get eaten up.

Comment: You don't have to move the prompt out of the function; just write it to standard error, like `read -p` does. `echo "type something: " >&2`.